# How do I request my customers to login in my private Nuget package server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server

I have an ASP.NET MVC website where customers log in using [ASP.NET Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity). I also have a private Nuget package server for my products (I followed [these instructions](https://adamtheautomator.com/nuget-server/) to create it).

How do I enforce login with ASP.NET Identity on the private Nuget package server?

Comment: why do you care "how" users authenticate for your feed? Or are you building your own package-server?

Comment: Do not use [AllowAnonymous] which allow users without login.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Is your MVC application provides access to the NuGet server?

Comment: @Tsahi: they are two different websites inside the IIS server. I would like to request authentication before downloading the NuGet packages.

Comment: I still don't get why would you need to access a NuGet server from your web app, but if that's your goal, you need to use impersonation. Here is some documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/aspnet/development/implement-impersonation

Comment: @Tsahi: I need to restrict the NuGet server access to authenticated (actual customers) users. How would you do it? I need something like this: https://nuget.devexpress.com/

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Nuget.Server and how it authenticates users. iirc, the impersonation API I lined to works with Windows authentication, and not forms or social authentication (using an external identity provider). It may not be helpful, but you'll have to find a way to translate your logged in user to the Nuget.Server user.